# Setting two elements to 100% width, yet one seems much wider than the other

Tags: html, css, width

I want two elements on my HTML form to have the same width.  I have set the width on both to 100% as seen below

```
input[type=text] {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 15px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #7ac9b7;
}

input[type=submit] {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 15px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #7ac9b7;
  background-color: #4180C5;
  color: aliceblue;
  font-size: 15px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

but when you look at my form (at least on Mac Google Chrome), https://jsfiddle.net/1v0xe9jx/1/, the text box is noticeably wider than the submit button.  How do I adjust my text box (or maybe the submit button is the problem) so that it appears to have the same width as the button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some HTML elements have predefined margin's and padding's, which one need to take into account when giving them a width.

These predefined values are set in the browsers user agent settings, and as they can (and for some element they do) have different values, this adds to the problem even when one doesn't give them a width.

In your case, not using margin's, there is a simple solution, where you set `box-sizing: border-box` to both the `input[type='text']` and `input[type='submit']`, to ensure a consistent layout cross browsers.

The `box-sizing: border-box` will make border's and padding's set size be included in the elements set width.

```css
#resize {
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 100px;
  margin-left: 50px;
  color: #41c54c;
}


/* line 8, /Users/davea/Documents/workspace/cindex/app/assets/stylesheets/form.css.scss */

div#envelope {
  width: 55%;
  margin: 10px 30% 10px 25%;
  padding: 10px 0;
  border: 2px solid gray;
  border-radius: 10px;
}


/* line 15, /Users/davea/Documents/workspace/cindex/app/assets/stylesheets/form.css.scss */

form {
  width: 70%;
  margin: 4% 15%;
  font-family: Manuelle;
  font-size: 14px;
}


/* line 21, /Users/davea/Documents/workspace/cindex/app/assets/stylesheets/form.css.scss */

header {
  background-color: #4180C5;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 12px;
  padding-bottom: 8px;
  margin-top: -11px;
  margin-bottom: -8px;
  border-radius: 10px 10px 0 0;
  color: aliceblue;
}


/* line 32, /Users/davea/Documents/workspace/cindex/app/assets/stylesheets/form.css.scss */

.field {
  padding-top: 10px;
}


/* Makes responsive fields.Sets size and field alignment.*/


/* line 37, /Users/davea/Documents/workspace/cindex/app/assets/stylesheets/form.css.scss */

input[type=text] {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 15px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #7ac9b7;
  box-sizing: border-box;            /*  added property  */
}


/* line 45, /Users/davea/Documents/workspace/cindex/app/assets/stylesheets/form.css.scss */

input[type=submit] {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 15px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #7ac9b7;
  background-color: #4180C5;
  color: aliceblue;
  font-size: 15px;
  cursor: pointer;
  box-sizing: border-box;            /*  added property  */
}


/* line 57, /Users/davea/Documents/workspace/cindex/app/assets/stylesheets/form.css.scss */

#submit:hover {
  background-color: black;
}


/* line 61, /Users/davea/Documents/workspace/cindex/app/assets/stylesheets/form.css.scss */

textarea {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 15px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #7ac9b7;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  resize: none;
}


/* line 70, /Users/davea/Documents/workspace/cindex/app/assets/stylesheets/form.css.scss */

input[type=text]:focus,
textarea:focus {
  border-color: #4697e4;
}
```

```html
<div id="content" style="background-color: #e0e0e0;">
  <h2>Create New Notification</h2>
  <form class="new_user_notification" id="new_user_notification" action="/user_notifications" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post">
    <input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" />
    <input type="hidden" name="authenticity_token" value="DHS408tHZXxdoZ/L2cUglHKCHIFbEkXuXNA+AG005Ikau/un0EIkS7MG8wVPgsPCSgxzmSrH0j8r99+06tpcgg==" />
    <input type="hidden" name="user_notification[id]" id="user_notification_id" />

    <div class="field">
      <label for="user_notification_crypto_currency_id">Crypto currency</label> <span class="required">*</span>
      <br>
      <select name="user_notification[crypto_currency_id]" id="user_notification_crypto_currency_id">
        <option value="">Select Currency</option>
        <option value="1020">Bitcoin</option>
        <option value="2077">Bitcoin Cash</option>
        <option value="2080">Dash</option>
        <option value="2075">Ethereum</option>
        <option value="2082">Ethereum Classic</option>
        <option value="2081">IOTA</option>
        <option value="2078">Litecoin</option>
        <option value="2084">Monero</option>
        <option value="2079">NEM</option>
        <option value="2083">NEO</option>
        <option value="2076">Ripple</option>
        <option value="2085">Stratis</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
      <label for="user_notification_price">Price</label> <span class="required">*</span>
      <br>
      <input size="30" type="text" name="user_notification[price]" id="user_notification_price" />
    </div>
    <div class="field">
      <label for="user_notification_buy">Condition</label>
      <br>
      <select name="user_notification[buy]" id="user_notification_buy">
        <option value="">Select Notification Time</option>
        <option value="false">Above</option>
        <option value="true">Below</option>
      </select>
    </div>

    <div class="actions buttonContainer">
      <input type="submit" name="commit" value="Submit" id="submit" class="button btn" data-disable-with="Submit" />
    </div>

  </form>


</div>
```

If one also use margin's, they will still add to the element's size and the space it occupies.

The solution for margin's is to use [CSS `calc()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/calc), i.e. like this `width: calc(100% - 30px)`, where the 30px is the sum of an element's left and right margin.

Answer (score 4):

Alternatively, *as tested on the js fiddle* that was linked to --

You could simply modify the `padding` property of the css selector:

```
input [type=text] {
  padding: 15px 0;
}
```

This is the simplest (and potentially most logical) fix - just add a **zero**. This *shorthand* sets the top and bottom padding to 15px, while setting the left and right to **0**, resulting in your desired effect.

It makes more sense then setting padding to 15px on all four sides, just to then set it to 0 on both the left and right -- as suggested in one of the other answers.

If you wanted to be more explicit, you could do away with the `padding` property and opt for this:

```
input [type=text] {
  padding-top: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
}
```

Either way, you aren't setting `padding` on all four sides just to negate it on the following two lines

Comment: This answer doesn't solve the issue. If you measure both elements after this change, they still aren't equally wide. Additionally, this also make the `input` lose its left/right padding, which looks very bad when users enter a value into it.

Comment: Yeah I have to agree wiht @LgSon.  Adding your logic -- https://jsfiddle.net/1v0xe9jx/1/ makes my cursor jammed right up against the text box, whcih looks ugly and is not what I want.

Answer (score 2):

You should add `box-sizing: border-box` to the text `input` CSS. This makes it so the `border` and `padding` are included in the width calculation. At least on Chrome on Mac, the user-agent stylesheet includes this for you on the submit `input` but not the text `input`, which leads to this discrepancy.

Answer (score 1):

Look at `box-sizing` in CSS. An `input` with 100% and a margin will overflow its container.

```css
.content{
  padding:0;
  margin:0 auto;
  width:80%;
  background:red;
  padding:10px 0;
}

.overflow{
  display:block;
  background:pink;
  width:100%;
  padding:15px;
}

.percentages{
  display:block;
  background:orange;
  width:80%;
  padding:10px 10%;
}

.border-box{
  display:block;
  background:aqua;
  width:100%;
  padding:15px;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="overflow">Overflowed</div>
  <div class="percentages">Percentages</div>
  <div class="border-box">Box Sizing Border Box</div>
</div>
```